# How to check .js file is really included?

Tags: javascript, developer-tools, web-inspector

I'm staring with javascript
When you include in the  a line like this:

```
<script src="/webapp/A/js/file.js"></script>
```

You are trying to include the file.js, **but is there any way to check that the file is being really included?**
I mean, if i write any other name for example file1234.js, i dont get any error message.

Tried inspecting in chrome and firefox.

Comment: If file is not found it must return 404. Which you can see in network tab of console.

Comment: if you didn't get any errors that's mean it's included, you can inspect your web page and hover over the js link /js/1234.js you can see the file from the browser

Comment: Note that in HTML, you **must** use simple quotes (`"`), not fancy quotes as you have in your question (`“`). Using what's in your question, nothing is loaded and no error is shown in the console, presumably because of the quotes.

Comment: If that is your _actual_ code, then the browser will not attempt to load anything at all - because it does not know what to do with the given type, `“text/javascript”`. Those "curly" quotes are not valid attribute delimiters in HTML, so they have become _part of the value_ you have given for that attribute. Use `"` or `'` as attribute value delimiters in HTML.

Comment: The Problem X is,
I've lot of .js import files for a webpage, if i remove some of those from (i.e. removing <script src=> tag), the page is still loading fine.
So, How do I check, where exactly those .js files were being used.

Comment: If you make the browser request a non-existing resource, then you should see an error message telling you about this in the browser console, and in the network panel you should see that the request this caused got a 404 response. (Assuming your server does not for some reason give a _different_ response for non-existing resources.)